# aws boto sns - get endpoint_arn by device token

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sns

Currently, If we want to add a device to an SNS application using:

```python
ep = SNSConnection.create_platform_endpoint(app_arn,device_token,user_data)
```

There is an option that the device was already added in the past.
To verify if the device is already added, we're using:

```python
def is_device_registered(device_token):
        list_of_endpoints = SNSConnection.list_endpoints_by_platform_application(AC.INPLAY_CHAT_APPLICATION_SNS_ARN)
        all_app_endpoints = list_of_endpoints['ListEndpointsByPlatformApplicationResponse']['ListEndpointsByPlatformApplicationResult']['Endpoints']
        for ep in all_app_endpoints:
            ep_device_token = ep['Attributes']['Token']
            if device_token == ep_device_token:
                endpoint_arn =  ep['EndpointArn']
                print 'Found an endpoint for device_token: %s, entry:%s' % (device_token,endpoint_arn)
                return endpoint_arn
        return None
```

which is very inefficient and can not be scaled.

is there a boto sns function that get the device_token and returns the endpoint_arn if exists?
(None if not).

Comment: Hey amit - did you ever find the best way to handle this?  Are you storing the endpoint arn or looking it up each time using the token?  Answer your own question if you found the "right" way to do this

Comment: we have an option to store it in a DB/Redis, But since the data is stored in AWS SNS, we think it will be usefull to retrieve it from there using API (boto in this case)

Answer (score 6):

Amazon gives you the arn on the Error Message. You can parse it from there. Not optimal, but saves some db lookup.

error: SNS ERROR - Could not subcribe user to SNSInvalidParameter: Invalid parameter: Token Reason: Endpoint arn:aws:sns:us-east-[rest of the ARN Key] already exists with the same Token, but different attributes. Here is some coffe with regex ready to go

```python
if err?
  log.error "SNS ERROR - Could not subcribe user to SNS" + err
  #Try to get arn from error

  result = err.message.match(/Endpoint(.*)already/)
  if result?.length
    #Assign and remove leading and trailing white spaces.
    result = result[1].replace /^\s+|\s+$/g, ""
    log.debug "found existing arn-> #{result} "
```

Comment: This should be the accept answer.  I will post a Django / Python version based on @fino answer.

Comment: 10x @fino - we hoped the solution will be in boto API.

Comment: Isn't this kinda ridiculous? What if the format of the error changes?

Comment: Oh my god it works perfectly. I don't need to list 2 million endpoints anymore!!!!

Comment: Seeing as this answer is a bit older - has anything changed in this regard? Is this still the best you can do, without copying endpoint arns to your own db? It doesn't really feel like a good solution, as it's entirely dependent on the error string never changing.

Answer (score 5):

Same answer as @fino but code for Django. Hope this help.

```python
import re

try:
    sns_connection = sns.connect_to_region(...)
    response = sns_connection.create_platform_endpoint(...)
    arn = response['CreatePlatformEndpointResponse']['CreatePlatformEndpointResult']['EndpointArn']
    return arn

except Exception, err:
    print err
    #try to get arn from error
    result_re = re.compile(r'Endpoint(.*)already', re.IGNORECASE)
    result = result_re.search(err.message)
    if result:
        arn = result.group(0).replace('Endpoint ','').replace(' already','')
        print arn
        return arn
    return ''
```

Comment: 10x @JohnPang.  - we hoped the solution will be in boto API.