# Send a push notification to a specific APNS token using AWS SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to send a basic APNS push notification to a specific APNS token using AWS SNS. All the examples I'm finding are how to store the token in SNS, subscribe to channels, and publish to channels.

I don't need that kind of usage with the application I'm building. The golang application decides which users a push needs to be sent to for which actions. Then it looks up the tokens for those users in the DB. All I need is a basic request to send a push notification to that token (preferably asynchronously).

Here is one of the examples I've looked at:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/sns/SNS.html#Publish-instance_method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To use the Publish action for sending a message to a mobile endpoint,
>   such as an app on a Kindle device or mobile phone, you must specify
>   the `EndpointArn`. The `EndpointArn` is returned when making a call with
>   the `CreatePlatformEndpoint` action.

The easiest way of getting the `EndpointArn` would be to store it along with or instead of the APNS token in your DB, assuming you are using `CreatePlatformEndpoint`. Otherwise have a look at this question: [Amazon SNS: How to get EndpointArn by token(registrationId) using amazon .net sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501373/amazon-sns-how-to-get-endpointarn-by-tokenregistrationid-using-amazon-net-sd)

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing. Before storing the apns token into the DB, I make a `CreatePlatformEndpoint` request and then store the resulting `EndpointArn` in the DB as well. When I publish, I publish to the `EndpointArn`. Seems like a bit of unnecessary overhead, but it works.